# Unable to run CSOM within the Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, nuget-package, csom

I am working on an Azure Function and trying to execute the CSOM code within that function

I am able to easily download and install Microsoft.SharePoint.Client packages, or, likewise, I am able to successfully download and install the Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM package

However, no matter what I do, the function refuses to find the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime DLL (even though that DLL IS present within the contents of the packages folder.

Also, when I try to download the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime directly from Nuget it fails saying that the restore failed.

I am at a loss. Can somebody help me on how to move forward?

Comment: What version of Azure Functions are you using? And what do you mean by "refuses to find" the runtime dll? Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: The statement 'using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime;' throws a compilation error.

However, I was able to find a solution as I don't need the Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Runtime.dll at all

Thank you very much for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I don't need a Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.dll at all and don't need SharePointOnlineCredentials class. I can just use Microsoft Graphs to get the items from the Sharepoint List